# C# , how to use Regex on a website to grab

Tags: c#, regex

When my button1 is clicked it runs this

```
 MatchCollection matchCollection = new Regex(@"(?<=/&gt;)\d+").Matches(new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.proxyserverlist24.top/feeds/posts/default")).GetResponse()).GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

Basicly, it's going to http://www.proxyserverlist24.top/feeds/posts/default
and trying to extract the numbers between /%gt; and lt;br

> /%gt;103.12.161.1:65103%lt;br /%gt;103.16.61.134:8080%lt;br
>   /%gt;103.21.77.106:8080%lt;br

How do I go about to grabbing those numbers?

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1070452) You cant have done much research because that is one of the most upvoted posts on the site

Comment: My code worked before, on a different site. Since that site went down I have to change the regex values

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/jsHTaq/1

Comment: Noone is trying to parse HTML in this question. I wonder if anyone even bothers looking up the meaning of *parse*, or at least read the post you are quoting. Regex is great for searching text and retrieving or replacing based on patterns. Regex is a great solution to the asked question.

Comment: @Denis: If all you want is each number, why not just use (\d+) instead of worrying about "%gt," or "%lt,br" ?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield OP is trying to extract proxy addresses in the form `x.x.x.x:xxxx`

Comment: @EZI: I understand that, but the regex pattern shown captures them one numeric element at a time. It's unclear if they want each element, or each address in a capture group.

Comment: @S.Kablar that value doesn't work
the site that I linked has much more numbers that are not between %gt and %lt,br. Once I click a button it will extract all the proxies from the site and display them in the listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to Regex. You can use xml parser(your link returns xml), and an html parser ([HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)) to parse text of "content" tag. So final code is:

```
IPAddress tempip;
int port;
List<IPEndPoint> proxies = null;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    var xml = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.proxyserverlist24.top/feeds/posts/default");
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    proxies = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
        .Select(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "content"))
        .SelectMany(x =>
        {
            doc.LoadHtml(x);
            return doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[not(span)]")
                        .SelectMany(n => n.Descendants())
                        .Select(n => n.InnerText.Split(":".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        .Where(n => n.Length == 2)
                        .Where(n => IPAddress.TryParse(n[0], out tempip))
                        .Where(n => int.TryParse(n[1], out port))
                        .Select(n => new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(n[0]), int.Parse(n[1])));
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

In fact a shorter regex solution is also possible, but is it not a good idea to use regex to parse xml or html as mentioned in comments.

Comment: I have solved it in an easier way by using Regex in this way : new Regex("(?<=&gt;)([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,5})(?=&lt;br)"